# Edit HTML table row populated with MySQL db in new page with a HTML Form using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

So, i'm coding a new CMS that is intended to commercials insert reports related to clients, but i need help with something, since i'm a bit noob with PHP and MySQL.

What i need to do, is to open a new page, with a HTML Form that i created and to populate it with the content of the row that i selected on the table.

In this case, "clients" (which are the content i need to edit), all of the them have unique ids.

I'll try to show what i want to do in this pictures below.

This is the table where the content is and i want to be able to click on the edit link on the right, and make it open on a the new page with the form all populated.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaXQt.png)

This is the form i need to be populated with the content of the selected row.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjWpw.png)

This is the code of the table:

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'minicms';

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('ERROR CONNECTING TO DB: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM clients';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-color">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Designação Social</th>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">NIF</th>
            <th scope="col">Rua</th>
            <th scope="col">Código Postal</th>
            <th scope="col">Localidade</th>
            <th scope="col">País</th>
            <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
            <th scope="col">Editar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['namefat'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['nif'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['street'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['postal'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['local'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['country'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                    <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                </tr>';
        }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the code of the form:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="namefat">Designação Social</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="namefat" class="form-control" id="namefat">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nome</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nif">NIF</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="nif" class="form-control" id="nif">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="street">Rua</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="street" class="form-control" id="street">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postal">Codigo Postal</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="postal" class="form-control" id="postal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="local">Localidade</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="local" class="form-control" id="local">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country">País</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" id="country">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

Hope i was able to explain my problem correctly

Comment: Are your rows and the form on the same page? If so you can use a onclick event where you use jquery to populate the fields of the form. If they are on diffrent pages you need to either pass the primary key of the row via post or querystring and make the form page a php page and grab the row information using another mysql query.

Comment: They are on different pages.

Comment: Add a form around the table with some sort of selector (probably a radio button) that has the primary key as its value and have the form post to the other page (dont forget a submit button), use PHP to grab the post information, run another query "select * from clients where [mypk] = '" .$myPostedVal ."'"; then use the returned rows to populate the value fields of the form.

Comment: Don't write code like this. Use a framework

Comment: i'm new to php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is put it inside bootstrap modal , right besides your ,

tr row

```
 echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['namefat'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['nif'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['street'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['postal'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['local'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['country'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                    <td><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal'.$rowId."><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal'.$rowId.'>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<!-- put your form code inside this  with jquery submit with ajax
   you can populate your entire form with values here 
 -->

<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="namefat">Designação Social</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="namefat" class="form-control" id="namefat">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Nome</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nif">NIF</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="nif" class="form-control" id="nif">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="street">Rua</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="street" class="form-control" id="street">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="postal">Codigo Postal</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="postal" class="form-control" id="postal">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="local">Localidade</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="local" class="form-control" id="local">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country">País</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" id="country">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
 </form> </div> </tr>';
```

This way you will have not even need to have a saperate page for changing data on submit of this ajax request or even the form you can refresh page saving extra time needed to create a new page and completing the editing without really changing a page

SO in place of this

```
?>
      <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['namefat'];?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['name'];?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['nif'];?>  </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['street'];?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['postal'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['local'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['country'];?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
<td><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo $row['id'];/* possible unique id */ ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?php echo $row['id'];/* possible unique id */ ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<!-- put your form code inside this  with jquery submit with ajax
   you can populate your entire form with values here 
 -->

<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="namefat">Designação Social</label>
    <br> 
    <input type="text" name="namefat" class="form-control" id="namefat" value="<?php echo $row['namefat'];?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Nome</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nif">NIF</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="nif" class="form-control" id="nif" value=" <?php echo $row['nif'];?> ">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="street">Rua</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="street" class="form-control" id="street" value="<?php echo $row['street'];?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="postal">Codigo Postal</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="postal" class="form-control" id="postal" value="<?php echo $row['postal'];?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="local">Localidade</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="local" class="form-control" id="local" value="<?php echo $row['local'];?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country">País</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" id="country" value="<?php echo $row['country'];?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>">

     <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo $row['id']; /* possible unique id */ ?>">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
 </form> </div>
</tr>

<?php
```

this will show a form inside every column , the its a matter of just adding bootstrap files , bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css in your php file script tag

you can read about it here

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: can't put it to work that way, somehow. i'm melting my brain off with this, right now.

Comment: Hi again. Somehow it is still not working, since now i have not working page error. I believe it is related to the php echo calls...

Comment: forget it, i solved it. i'm dumb sometimes. i forgot to remove the previous echo call. it's working now. thank you very much!